# Is random walk stationary or non-stationary?

Tags: time-series, stationarity, random-walk

I'm confused with the concept "stationarity".
Reference: https://otexts.com/fpp3/stationarity.html

I believe random walk is non-stationary and change (difference) in random walk is stationary.  The characteristics of random walk are these below:

> - long periods of apparent trends up or down
> - sudden and unpredictable changes in direction.

On the other hand, this book mentions time series with aperiodic cyclic behavior are considered stationary. **In my opinion, this "cyclic behavior" is very similar to the behavior of random walk.**

> Some cases can be confusing — a time series with cyclic behaviour (but with no trend or seasonality) is stationary. This is because the cycles are not of a fixed length, so before we observe the series we cannot be sure where the peaks and troughs of the cycles will be.

How should I interpret these passages?

Comment: A random walk has no stationary distribution, hence cannot be [stationary.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process#Definition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A random walk $\langle X_t\rangle$ is defined as

\begin{align}X_t &:= X_{t-1} + Z_t\\ &= \sum_{j=1}^t Z_j,\tag 1\label 1\end{align}

where $\langle Z_t\rangle$ is a discrete time, pure random process with mean being $\mu,$  and variance $\sigma^2.$ So, from $\eqref 1, ~\mathbb E[X_t] = \mu t; ~~\operatorname{Var}[X_t] = \sigma^2 t,$ which imply the mean and variance vary over $t.$ This certainly means random walk process $\langle X_t\rangle$ is non-stationary.

Now $\nabla X_t = Z_t,$ which is definitely stationary as it is a purely random process.

Cyclical variations are intuitively speaking manifestations of *oscillations* not having a fixed period.

Stationarity means there is no systematic change in mean and variance: properties of a section should resemble that of other section.

So, what the authors in the given quote clearly meant is that presence of cyclical behavior needn't imply non-stationarity. Because they, by definition, aren't of fixed length.

Random walks on other hand exhibit changes in variance over time, with "sudden and unpredictable changes in direction."

---

### Reference:

$\rm [I]$ The Analysis of Time Series, *Chris Chatfield,* CRC Press, $2003.$

Comment: *pure random process* does not sound like an unambiguous technical term. A martingale difference sequence would be closer to one. Moreover, a more widespread definition of a random walk would require $\mu=0$. $\mu\neq 0$ produces a random walk with a drift.

Comment: Well, purely random process refers to a  sequence of $\rm i.i.d.$ random variables with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2.$

Comment: Saw your updated comment. Yes. I followed Chatfield's treatment of the same.